# How can I calculate the computational complexity of an equation composed of $2n$ multiplications and $2nm^2$ additions?

Tags: computational-complexity

I want to calculate the computational complexity in term of the big ($\cal O$). My equation is:

[image]

It composed of 2n multiplications and $2nm^2$ additions. The complexity of this equation is it ${\cal O}(2n + 2nm^2)$ or ${\cal O}(2n \cdot 2nm^2)$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4453590/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51476/5038, https://mathoverflow.net/q/422839/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151684/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4):

If the computation were done as it is written,
there are $2N$ multiplications and $2N$ additions/subtractions inside the absolute value, but that is performed once for each $(r,s)$ pair, and there are approximately $M^2/2$ of those pairs, so $O(M^2 N)$.  However, it's more efficient to first calculate and remember the $M$ numbers $\sum_j a_{rj} W_j$, rather than recalculating them each time. That would make the complexity
$O(M^2 + N)$.

Comment: I did not understand very well, could you detailed it please ? for example use O( max ( 2n, $M^2$)) = O ($M^2$)

Answer (score 1):

Consider how we use Big-Oh notation...

It may help to try to fit one term inside the other.  For example, $O(n)$ means that the algorithm runs in time $c (n)$ for some $c$.  $O(nm^2)$ means that the algorithm runs in time $c (nm^2)$ for some $c$.

You claim the running time is in $2n + 2nm^2$.  So can you fit the number $2n + 2nm^2 < c(n)$ for some $c$.  I suggest you try to fit $2n + 2nm^2 < c (nm^2)$.  If you make $c  =3$, Then $2n + 2nm^2 < 3(nm^2)$.  So we know it is $O(nm^2)$.

---

But this is only part of the story.  This just means that the algorithm will take more time than $c(nm^2)$ for some $c$.  Robert Israel suggests using a different method.  The idea is to store the two innermost sums in memory.  Then the outermost sums take time $c(m^2)$ times the time to calculate the innermost sums.  But you stored the innermost sums in memory, so they each only require $1$ unit of time to copy.  So the time $c(m^2)$ times the time to calculate the innermost sums is really $c(m^2) 1$.

Now, the analysis is a little tricky.  Remember that we first went through the innermost loops?  There were $n$ values, so this clearly takes time $O(n)$.  And you should get that the outer loops take time $c(m^2)1 = O(m^2)$.  So what is $O(n) + O(m^2)$?  Well, this is like comparing apples and oranges, because we don't know which is bigger.  So in this case, we just add the two together, to get $O(n + m^2)$, which is the same as $O(m^2 + n)$.  We can't simplify this sum any further, without more information.

---

If you knew that $m^2 > n$, then the algorithm could finish in time $O(m^2)$.  If you knew that $n > m^2$, then the algorithm could finish in time $O(n)$.  I hope you have an idea of why this is.